# change default value to a column through a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, rails-migrations, mysql-5.6

I have an existing table in which default value of column is already set. This table contains lot of data in it. **I don't want to change any of exiting record in table(don't want to change column of exiting record), but from here onwards I want to change the default value of that column.** How do I do that?

Rails version: Rails 4.0.13
Ruby version: ruby 2.2.10p489

Answer (score 0):

Consider I want to change default value of a field(is_male) in table(users). My users table contains lot of data in it where I want to change the default value of is_male column which is of type tinyint, from true to false.

I have created a migration using:

```
rails g migration add_default_false_to_is_male_for_users
```

made below changes in migration file:

```
class AddDefaultFalseToColumnNameTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_default :users, :is_male, false
  end
    
  def down
    change_column_default :users, :is_male, true
  end
end
```

It won't change existing data.